# How to combine two sets of data with differences in merge-index strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two csv-files with soccer data. They hold different data of the same and different games (partial overlap). Normally I would do a merge with df.merge, but the problem is, that the nomenclature differs for some teams in the two Datasets. E.g. "Atletic Bilbao" is called "Club Atletic" in the second set.

Therefore I would like to norm the team-naming on the two Datasets in order to be able to do a simple df.merge-operation on dates and teamnames. At the moment this would result in extra-lines, when a team has different names in the two sets.

So my main question is: How can I norm the teamnames in the two sets easily, without having to analyse all the differences "by hand" and hardcode "replace"-operations on one of the sets?

Dataset1 is downloadable here: https://data.fivethirtyeight.com/#soccer-spi 
Dataset2 is not available freely, but it looks like this:

```
hometeam            awayteam    date                homeproba   drawproba   awayproba   homexg  awayxg  
Manchester United   Leicester   2018-08-10 22:00:00 0.2812      0.3275      0.3913      1.5137  1.73813
```

--Edit after first comments--

So the main question is: How could I automatically analyse the differences in the two datasets naming? Helpful facts:

- As the sets hold wholes seasons, the overlap per team name is at least 30+ games.
- Most of the teams have same names, name differences are the smaller part of the team names.
- Most name differences have at least a common substring.
- Both datasets have date-information of the games.
- We know, a team plays only one game a day.

So if Dataset1 says:

```
1.1.2018 Real - Atletic Club
```

And Dataset2 says:

```
1.1.2018 Real - Atletic Bilbao
```

We should be able to analyse that: {'Atletic Club':'Atletic Bilbao'}

Comment: Nobody knows if "Club Atletic" and "Atletic Bilbao" is the same team - except yourself. You must provide a dictionary of equivalences.

Comment: But it might be analyzable, because they play against "known" teams on "known" dates very often.

Comment: Then this becomes a broad research question, and broad research questions, sadly, are off topic on SO.

Comment: So I guess my main question is - how can I write such a dict automatically, if there are at least 30 games per team overlapping in the Datasets.

Comment: ... and most teams have same strings or at least same substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I could solve this finally:

```
import pandas as pd

df_teamnames = pd.merge(dataset1,dataset2,on=['hometeam','date'])
df_teamnames = df_teamnames[['awayteam_x','awayteam_y']]
df_teamnames = df_teamnames.drop_duplicates()
```

This gives you a dataframe holding each team's name existing in both datasets like this:

```
1    Marseille      Marseille
2    Atletic Club   Atletic Bilbao
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are compatible (and correct), this should probably work to generate a translation dictionary. This type of thing is always super fragile I think though, and you shouldn't really rely on it.

```
import pandas as pd

names_1 = dataset1['hometeam'].unique().tolist()
names_2 = dataset2['hometeam'].unique().tolist()

mapping_dict = dict()
for common_name in set(names_1).intersection(set(names_2)):
    mapping_dict[common_name] = common_name

unknown_1 = set(names_1).difference(set(names_2))
unknown_2 = set(names_2).difference(set(names_1))

trim_df1 = dataset1.loc[:, ['hometeam', 'awayteam', 'date']]
trim_df2 = dataset2.loc[:, ['hometeam', 'awayteam', 'date']]

aligned_data = trim_df1.join(trim_df2, on = ['hometeam', 'date'], how = 'inner', lsuffix = '_1', rsuffix = '_2')

for unknown_name in unknown_1:
    matching_name = aligned_data.loc[aligned_data['awayteam_1'] == unknown_name, 'awayteam_2'].unique()
    if len(matching_name) != 1:
        raise ValueError("Couldn't find a unique match")
    mapping_dict[unknown_name] = matching_name[0]
    unknown_2.remove(matching_name[0])

if len(unknown_2) != 0:
    raise ValueError("We have extra team names for some reason")
```

Comment: Ok thx, this looks good. I will try to add a double check (because if it finds one match in one particular game, it should be able to find a second match in a second one) and then use this.

Comment: This is checking to make sure that all home games match in date, not that one game matches. You could check away games too I guess. It's very likely that minor inconsistency between your data sets will break this approach in general.

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't get that. It lies in the .all(), right? I didn't know that before.

Comment: Just thought it might also be interesting to make an inner merge on date and hometeam. Then you get two awayteam-columns per game, that you could compare and search for differences ...

Comment: It raises "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects". I guess I have to have all the same dates in both datasets? Because this is not the case, they hold data from different periods (with an overlap, of course...).

Comment: Ahh, that's tough - inner join's a pretty good idea, I've edited the answer to use it instead (although the same problem of minor inconsistencies will be present)

Comment: Ah, saw your comment just know, after I posted my own solution.